# error TS2322: Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, fetch-api, ngfor

While iam trying to fetch data getting this error
user.service.ts[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xtfS.png)

```
export class UserService {
baseurl: string="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

listUsers(){
  //this.http.get(this.baseurl+ 'users').subscribe(responseData => console.log(responseData));
return this.http.get(this.baseurl + 'users');
}
}
```

list-users.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-users',
  templateUrl: './list-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-users.component.css']
})
export class ListUsersComponent implements OnInit {
   listUsers!: Observable<any>;
constructor(private userService: UserService){}
  ngOnInit(): void {
this.listUsers=this.userService.listUsers();
   
  }
```

list.users.component.html

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let user of listUsers">
        {{ user.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

while iam tring to get data through api iam facing this error

Comment: I am also facing similar issue did you found any solution

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of angular (14) you have to make a little change in the **list-users.component.ts**.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-list-users',
      templateUrl: './list-users.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./list-users.component.css']
    })
    export class ListUsersComponent implements OnInit {
       listUsers: yourInterfaceName[]=[];
    constructor(private userService: UserService){}
      ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.listUsers().subscribe((res)=>{
      this.listUsers = res;
    }) 
  }
```